# Why do some app makers limit their app to certain regions?

Tags: mobile, app

For example, many dating apps are limited to only certain cities of the USA. Or, they launch first in only regions and then may be unlocked across the country.

Why the restriction?
Why wouldn't you want your app to be used by as many people as possible?

Comment: Note: "app" is an abbreviation of "application", not an initialism or acronym.

Comment: think about marketing costs

Comment: There might be legal requirements for a dating app for example. Are you sure your app couldn’t fall foul of Serbian or Ugandan law? And do you know what the consequences would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dating app may be a good example here. First, when you start you typically do not have a lot of resources so immediate brought interest may bring the system to its knees and give users a bad experience. You want to start small and gradually scale up. Plus, for dating you want the first pool of users to be local to each other. Having 1000 users scattered across the country would defeat the purpose of the app.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, legal restrictions may apply, so app developers may choose to limit availability to regions for which legalities have been checked. States and countries may have different age restrictions and consent laws, and violations may be pretty costly.

Comment: Or you might just not know the legalities and checking outweighs your income from that region.